# What does the dot . mean here in the gitignore

Tags: git, gitignore

I have searched online and on git website for this gitignore explanation but cant find an answer.

What does the dot `.` mean here in the gitignore line `.env.development.local`?

```
# misc
.DS_Store
.env.local
.env.development.local
.env.test.local
.env.production.loc
```

Comment: It's literally just a dot in the name of the file. A leading `.` in the name means it is excluded from e.g. `ls` by default (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/506233), but isn't otherwise special.

Comment: So you mean env.development.local is a filename ok thanks

Comment: No, `.env.development.local` is a filename. Other examples of files with a leading `.` include `.gitignore`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those files are the `.` files in your folder.

`.DS_STORE` exists only for Mac, has something to do with Mac folder structure.

The different `.env` files are used in different development teams depending on the situation.

Environment variables are more common for something like a `nodejs` application like an API which has to have a database url or something

For example:

- `.env` is the main environment variables file.
- `.env.development` are environment variable file for development only
- `.env.local` are enviornment variables only for local

The files are above are just `example` type standards. I personally don't follow all those files actually.

Comment: What's the difference with `.env.development.local` and `.env.development` I mean during development what would go in one and not in the other?

Comment: It depends on the project holder and how they want it. For example: I might make `.env.development.local` like if you have a different port for database than the one in `.env.development`. You could even say: `.env.fjejfrgnergergj.local` and no one would mind since it was your decision as a project holder/maintainer.

Comment: All of this has to do with mainly projects that are open-source and open to contributions. Check our some git repos and see for yourself! It is an interesting topic to look into of how teams manage `.env` files.